# NestJS HttpService All Method API Call is not working when Interceptor is used

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

NestJS API App use HttpService to call Another API and It works when no custom interceptor is used.
The HttpService API call is executed but it is not reached to another API and could not see the response.

This is get call code

```
 get(path: string, body: any = {}): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    console.log('DomainAPI Response Begining');
    const url = this.baseURL + path;
    this.updateLastUtilizedTimestamp();
    return this.httpService.get(url, { validateStatus: null }).pipe(
      tap(data => {
        console.log('DomainAPI Response Tap', data);
      }),
      retryWhen(
        this.rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy({
          numberOfAttempts: 3,
          delayTime: 200,
          ignoredErrorCodes: [500],
        }),
      ),
      catchError(this.formatErrors),
    );
  }
```

if any custom interceptor is used, I found the following when debug.

```
arguments:TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

The Postman shows the following response.

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": {
        "Title": "TypeError",
        "Type": "Error",
        "Detail": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Observable'\n    |     property 'operator' -> object with constructor 'CatchOperator'\n    --- property 'caught' closes the circle",
        "Status": "Status",
        "Extension": ""
    },
    "timestamp": "Exception - AllExceptionsFilter 2019-12-26T17:29:42.447Z"
}
```

I changed the above as below but still it is not working

```
get(path: string, body: any = {}) {
    console.log('DomainAPI Response Begining');
    const url = this.baseURL + path;
    this.updateLastUtilizedTimestamp();
    return this.httpService.get(url, { validateStatus: null }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        console.log('DomainAPI Response Tap', response.data);
        return response.data;
      }),
    );
  }
```

It gives the following response in the postman

```
{
    "data": {
        "_isScalar": false,
        "source": {
            "_isScalar": false,
            "source": {
                "_isScalar": false
            },
            "operator": {}
        },
        "operator": {}
    }
}
```

Please advise

Comment: Have found any solution. I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
async get(path: string, body: any = {}): Promise<any> {
    ...
    const res = await this.httpService.get(url, { validateStatus: null }).toPromise();

    return res.data;
  }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26177428)

Answer (score 0):

```
get(path: string, body: any = {}) {
   ...
    return this.httpService.get(url, { validateStatus: null })
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => this.logger.error(err));
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide an explanation in order to improve your answer and make it more understandable for the community

Answer (score 0):

Converting to a promise using the .toPromise() method has been deprecated because we are working with observables and a promise returns only one value while observables could return no value or more that one value (see more @: [Conversion to Promises](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise)). So as an example using the question above the solution would be:

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

get(path: string, body: any = {}): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    console.log('DomainAPI Response Begining');
    const url = this.baseURL + path;
    this.updateLastUtilizedTimestamp();
 
    return await lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get(url, { validateStatus: null })
      .pipe(
      tap(data => {
        console.log('DomainAPI Response Tap', data);
      }),
      retryWhen(
        this.rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy({
          numberOfAttempts: 3,
          delayTime: 200,
          ignoredErrorCodes: [500],
        }),
      ),
      catchError(this.formatErrors),
    ));
  }
```

Basically all you have to do is wrap the whole http request with firstValueFrom or lastValueFrom, in this case lastValueFrom is what would be appropriate. Visit the link to the documentation on Conversion to promises above by rxjs to know more about this.

NOTE: I added just the lastValueFrom import only as a clear indicator of what is needed.

This is another example using my own code:

```
async send_otp(
    phone: string,
    channel: string,
    ): Promise<Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>> {
    return await lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .post(`/messaging/otp/`, {
          sender: 'Oyinkayy',
          destination: '234' + String(phone).slice(1),
          length: 6,
          channel: channel,
          reference: '',
        })
        .pipe(
          tap((resp) => console.log(resp)),
          map((resp) => {
            return resp.data;
          }),
          tap((data) => console.log(data)),
          catchError(async (err) => {
            return err;
          }),
        ),
    );
   }
```